# Fluid Simulation script fails to execute properly if mouse is moving while page is loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webgl

I found [this](https://github.com/x8BitRain/react-webgl-fluid/blob/master/assets/js/fluid-init.js) script which is a React implementation of [Pavel Dobryakov's WebGL Fluid Simulation](https://github.com/PavelDoGreat/WebGL-Fluid-Simulation/blob/master/script.js) and I wanted to use it on my website.

In the React implementation the first problem I had was that the simulation would break if the cursor interacted with the text above it since the event listener was added to the canvas - and the fix I found for it was to add the listener to the window instead, like this:

```
// original code
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    let pointer = pointers[0];
    if (pointer.down) { return; }
    let posX = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetX);
    let posY = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetY);
    updatePointerMoveData(pointer, posX, posY);
});

// the fixed version
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    let pointer = pointers[0];
    if (pointer.down) { return; }
    let posX = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetX);
    let posY = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetY);
    updatePointerMoveData(pointer, posX, posY);
});
```

Now the problem is that when you're moving your mouse while the page is still loading (for example after a page refresh) the script gets broken and the fluid simulation never starts painting on the canvas. If the mouse is staying outside of the window or stays in one place before the script gets to load the simulation works fine. Does anyone have any idea how could I fix this?

This is the fluid-init.js:

```
let canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('fluid-canvas')[0];
resizeCanvas();

/* the code is very long so I can't post it here but it's in the link above */

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  let posX = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetX);
  let posY = scaleByPixelRatio(e.offsetY);
  let pointer = pointers.find(function (p) {
    return p.id == -1;
  });
  if (pointer == null) {
    pointer = new pointerPrototype();
  }
  updatePointerDownData(pointer, -1, posX, posY);
});

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  let pointer = pointers[0];
  if (pointer.down) {
    return;
  }
  let posX = scaleByPixelRatio(e.clientX);
  let posY = scaleByPixelRatio(e.clientY);
  updatePointerMoveData(pointer, posX, posY);
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  updatePointerUpData(pointers[0]);
});

canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let touches = e.targetTouches;
  while (touches.length >= pointers.length) {
    pointers.push(new pointerPrototype());
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
    let posX = scaleByPixelRatio(touches[i].pageX);
    let posY = scaleByPixelRatio(touches[i].pageY);
    updatePointerDownData(pointers[i + 1], touches[i].identifier, posX, posY);
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener(
  'touchmove',
  function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let touches = e.targetTouches;
    for (let i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
      let pointer = pointers[i + 1];
      if (!pointer.down) {
        continue;
      }
      let posX = scaleByPixelRatio(touches[i].pageX);
      let posY = scaleByPixelRatio(touches[i].pageY);
      updatePointerMoveData(pointer, posX, posY);
    }
  },
  false
);

window.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
  let touches = e.changedTouches;
  let loop = function (i) {
    let pointer = pointers.find(function (p) {
      return p.id == touches[i].identifier;
    });
    if (pointer == null) {
      return;
    }
    updatePointerUpData(pointer);
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) loop(i);
});

function updatePointerDownData(pointer, id, posX, posY) {
  pointer.id = id;
  pointer.down = true;
  pointer.moved = false;
  pointer.texcoordX = posX / (canvas.width / 2);
  pointer.texcoordY = 1 - posY / (canvas.height / 2);
  pointer.prevTexcoordX = pointer.texcoordX;
  pointer.prevTexcoordY = pointer.texcoordY;
  pointer.deltaX = 0;
  pointer.deltaY = 0;
  pointer.color = generateColor();
}

function updatePointerMoveData(pointer, posX, posY) {
  pointer.prevTexcoordX = pointer.texcoordX;
  pointer.prevTexcoordY = pointer.texcoordY;
  pointer.texcoordX = posX / canvas.width;
  pointer.texcoordY = 1.0 - posY / canvas.height;
  pointer.deltaX = correctDeltaX(pointer.texcoordX - pointer.prevTexcoordX);
  pointer.deltaY = correctDeltaY(pointer.texcoordY - pointer.prevTexcoordY);
  pointer.moved = Math.abs(pointer.deltaX) > 0 || Math.abs(pointer.deltaY) > 0;
}

function updatePointerUpData(pointer) {
  pointer.down = false;
}

function correctDeltaX(delta) {
  let aspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
  if (aspectRatio < 1) {
    delta *= aspectRatio;
  }
  return delta;
}

function correctDeltaY(delta) {
  let aspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
  if (aspectRatio > 1) {
    delta /= aspectRatio;
  }
  return delta;
}
```

and this is my Fluid.jsx component:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Fluid = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = '/src/assets/fluid-init.js';
    script.async = true;
    script.type = 'module';

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return <canvas className="fluid-canvas"></canvas>;
};
```

I tried changing the mousedown event to a mouseover one and it works fine now but the performance is much worse so I don't think this is the solution.

Comment: What errors are displayed in the brouser console?

Comment: No errors at all unfortunately